# rspec for initialize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have written a initialize method in my model ( non-activerecord) I tried to write rspec for that initialize method, but not sure how can i write that. Please help me.

Here is my model

```
class Sample

  ATTRIBUTES = %w{ picture_id owner_id hr_width hr_height thumb_width 
  thumb_height thumb_url journal is_border lr_url }.map! { |s| s.to_sym }.freeze

  attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES

  require 'httpclient'

  def initialize(*h)
    if h.length == 1 && h.first.kind_of?(Hash)
      h.first.each { |k,v| send("#{k}=",v) }
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Despite my answer, I don't think that stackoverflow is a place for such questions.

Answer (score 1):

Method `initialize` is aimed to construct a new instance. It is called whenever method `new` is called.

You can write smth. like:

```
let(:sample) { Sample.new() }

it 'construct new sample' do
  here you should to check whatever you want
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`initialize` is private method, thus you should not explicitly test it. If it has side effects, stub environment to expect these. If it does not have side effects just don't test it.